# ViewState documentation for standard server controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate, asp.net-4.0

Anybody knows where to find documentation (or an easy way to figure out, using reflector for example) about which properties a given asp.net server control stores in viewstate/controlstate?

Thanks in advance

Added more info:
My current strategy is a trial, error, and undecoding the base64 view state from the html page to figure out what is stored. Anyway this technique is pretty limited as it depends on the server control properties having a non default value. So I would need to modify every property in a given server control to check. Very tedious in my opinion. I was looking for something better.

Comment: a good link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Do you know which control you're interested in, specifically?

Comment: Not interested in any in particular. I know (more or less) the basis of ViewState ControlState. But I was looking for documentation. For instance do you know which properties a DataGrid control stores in ViewState or ControlState in .net 2.0? And in .net 4.0? I think this information is necessary when deciding if you want to enabled/disable viewstate and to decide what to do in a Page_Load... check for ispostback or not,...

Answer (score 0):

According to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx
Asp.net stores control properties in viewstate during postbacks example Text property of a label and button etc.